# How to properly generate a random password with the window.crypto property?

Tags: javascript, random, window.crypto

The `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)` or `Math.ceil(Math.random() * 100)` method of generating a random number isn't the most cryptographically secure. I want to use this method in a random Password application, I'm trying to use the window.crypto property. Here's what I have set up, but it seems to return an empty value and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```js
const array = new Uint32Array(1);
window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);

let chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
let pwordLength = 12;
let password = '';

for (let i = 0; i <= pwordLength; i++) {
  let randomNumber = array * chars.length;
  password += chars.substring(randomNumber, randomNumber + 1);
}
console.log(`Password is ${password}`);
```

Comment: Your `randomNumber` is way out of range for [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)

Comment: Also, your randomNumber can be any huge number, not 0-1.

Comment: Also also, your randomNumber is an array.

Comment: @funkizer `randomNumber` isn't an array

Comment: I mean you're multiplying with an array. `let randomNumber = array * chars.length` is always `0`.

Comment: Actually it's `NaN`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate a `Uint32Array` with the same length as your `chars` list. Then loop over them to get a random value. By using `%` we can ensure we never exceed the given length ([remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder))

```js
let chars = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&*()ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
let pwordLength = 12;
let password = '';

const array = new Uint32Array(chars.length);
window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);

for (let i = 0; i < pwordLength; i++) {
  password += chars[array[i] % chars.length];
}


console.log(`Password is ${password}`);
```

Comment: note that (in the general case) using `%` will lead to bias and isn't recommended, but here it's probably OK because `chars.length` is known to be small. we can calculate the probability as the first 40 entries in `chars` being preferred ~1e-8 more